# How does cin convert chars in their corresponding types

Tags: c++, input, char, ascii, cin

i have a question about " how does cin converts chars in their corresponding types" , because i'm a bit confused about this matter .

For example we have : int a ; cin >> a ;
And if input is for example 3 , i know that cin takes this as character and converts it to int , but how does it convert it , clearly how cin can converts char (3) to int (3) , what kind of conversion does it use , because if we convert char 3 to int with typecast , int value will be 
ASCII code for '3' .

So , can anyone explain this matter to mee in great details  , please ?

Comment: Given a string of digits such as `"6481"`, can you parse and produce `6481`? If you can, then you know the answer already; if you cannot, then you wouldn't understand the answer to your question also. Know the basic firsts, and ask a simpler question such as : **how to parse `"6481"` and produce 6481?**

Comment: It's more-or-less similar to scanning for a sequence of digit characters, and calling `atoi` on the result.

Comment: In great details - a book could (read on operator '>>' overloading). Apart from that - it's a string that's being converted. From that perspective char(3) and int(3) are equally the same string: "3", which then gets parsed into a char array, and into the specific type.

Comment: If we check e.g. [this `operator>>` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt), you see that the input operator calls [`num_get::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get). That function in turn calls the protected `do_get` function. The last link (reference for `num_get::get` and `num_get::do_get`) documents the process very thoroughly, including further reference links.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen Whatever else it does, it cannot call `atoi`, because `atoi` doesn't do any of the necessary error checking.  (In the end, this is the same reason as to why you'd never use `atoi` in production code either.)

Comment: @JamesKanze that's why I said it was *similar* to - I never said it actually called `atoi`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conversion occurs in three successive stages, detailed in [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get). Essentially what happens is that the characters are taken from the input stream buffer and converted to their corresponding types through conversion specifiers obtained through iterating over each character. Since your example uses an integer the conversion specifier is that of `long`.  Those conversion specifiers are, through an implementation-defined manner, used to convert the input to the type of the variable.

Comment: @user80755 Can you consider accepting the answer? It helps a lot.